# Correct implementation of anchor tag

Tags: html, xhtml, anchor

I am wondering if there is a correct way to implement the anchor tag as I have seen the following examples `<p id="somename">text</p>`, `<h1 id="someheader">header</h1>`, etc

This then referenced as `<a href="#somename">Link</a>` or `<a href="#someheader">Link</a>`. I am aware that an anchor can also implemented as `<p><a name="somename"></a>text</p>`.

Aside from the ID attribute being used for CSS and Javascript, would it still be considered acceptable to use the ID attribute as an anchor? What other issues can there be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Aside from the ID attribute being used for CSS and Javascript, would it still be considered acceptable to use the ID attribute as an anchor?

Yes. Using an id is the modern approach. It is a generic way to identify part of a document. Being able to reuse it for other things (CSS, JS, etc) that need to identify part of a document is an advantage).

> What other issues can there be?

It isn't supported by Netscape 4 (which you probably shouldn't care about).

Comment: So even if I use the name ID attribute for other functions e.g. CSS, JS, anchor references, etc, it won't cause potential conflicts?

Comment: Not sure on this, but I imagine the anchors will fail to work if you modify the ID attribute (using JS, etc.) after the DOM has loaded. Simply reading the ID in CSS and JS shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey — No. Reading a property in multiple places doesn't cause conflicts.

Comment: @shrodes — I've never seen a case when it made sense to change an id with JavaScript.

Comment: @Quentin - no, of course not, but the OP asked what other issues there could be, and I believe there could be issues if the ID changes :)